# Does Marius sell out the revolutionary cause at the end in Les Miserables?

Tags: les-miserables

In the movie version of Les Miserables, the final scene is the very upper class and opulent wedding of Marius and Cosette.  Is Marius completely selling out the revolutionary cause and abandoning all his friends who have died?  This point seems to be glossed over in the movie and Marius isn't portrayed in any negative way for this, but in my mind should be very damning of him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest he's moved on.

The revolution has been crushed and his friends are dead.  No one's going to rise up for a long time.  He can dwell in unhappiness, rebel again (probably by himself and die) or carry on with his life with Cosette.

He chose the latter.

Comment: While the answer is not bad and *Marius* was a likable character after all, there is still a bit of a strange by-taste to his actions. Given that he only commited himself to the revolution once he thought he had lost *Cosette*, he never seemed to stand behind the cause with his full heart and it really seemed like once *Cosette* was there again, the revolution wasn't needed as a distraction anymore. Similar to other movies where the the death of a friend is forgotten some minutes later, *Marius* just seemed too happy at his opulent wedding and didn't think about revolution anymore in any way.